# extent report with multiple classes

Tags: java, selenium, report

all test cases from different classes are not running with extent report. 
one class in extent report
second class is forgot password
third class is login
i want to run both classes login and password together and want to create single report for both

```
       package Pedagogy;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
        import org.openqa.selenium.By;
        import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
        import org.testng.annotations.Test;
        import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
        import common.generalmail2;




        public class forgotPassword extends generalmail2{

            ArrayList<String> pathlist=new ArrayList<String>();
            String btn = "";
            String path= "";
            generalmail2  generalMail = new generalmail2();



            @Test
            public void Regestration_test() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                logger = report.startTest("ForgotPassword");
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("forgotpassword")).click();
                getLogger().log(LogStatus.PASS ,"got the forgot password id");
                getLogger().log(LogStatus.INFO , "forgotpassword page is open");
                validationTest("Sheet3");

            }

            public void validationTest(String sheet) throws Exception {

                Selenium_read obj = new Selenium_read();
                ArrayList<ArrayList> tablelist=obj.readExcel(sheet);
                System.out.println(tablelist);
                for (ArrayList<String> row : tablelist){
                    Forgotpassword_method(row.get(0),row.get(1));
                }

                Forgotpassword_method1();
                Forgotpassword_method2();       
            }

            public void Forgotpassword_method(String email, String snapshot)throws Exception {


                WebElement email_id= getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='forgotPasswordForm']/div[1]/div/input"));
                email_id.clear();
                String myWindowHandle = getDriver().getWindowHandle();
                getDriver().switchTo().window(myWindowHandle);
                WebElement email_id1= getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='forgotPasswordForm']/div[1]/div/input"));
                email_id1.sendKeys(email);
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='forgotPasswordForm']/div[2]/div/button[2]")).click();

            }

            public void Forgotpassword_method1()throws Exception {

                getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
                getDriver().get("https://mail.google.com/");
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("kunal@pedagogy.study");
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='identifierNext']/content/span")).click();
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("pedagogy@123");
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                getLogger().log(LogStatus.INFO , "successfully open email");
                List<WebElement> email = getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("div.xT>div.y6>span>b"));
                for(WebElement emailsub : email){
                if(emailsub.getText().equals("Pedagogy : Password Reset") == true){

                       emailsub.click();
                       break;
                    }
                }
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                String mytext = getDriver().findElement(By.partialLinkText("http://52.89.55.95:3000/changepassword?email=kunal@pedagogy.study&token=")).getText();
                getDriver().get(mytext);
            }

            public void Forgotpassword_method2()throws Exception {

                getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("Pedagogy@123");
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='confirmPassword']")).sendKeys("Pedagogy@123");
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("html/body/app-root/app-changepassword/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/button")).click();
                getLogger().log(LogStatus.INFO , "Successfully change the password");


            }


            public void switchToTab() { 
                getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
                getDriver().switchTo().defaultContent(); 
            }



            public void setButton(String str){
                btn=str;
            }


            public void setPath(String str){
                path=str;
            }

        }



    package Pedagogy;


    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import common.generalmail2;




    public class Registration extends generalmail2 {

            ArrayList<String> pathlist=new ArrayList<String>();
            String btn = "";
            String path= "";
            generalmail2  generalMail = new generalmail2();



        @Test
        public void Regestration_test() throws Exception {
            logger = report.startTest("SignUp");
            getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div/a")).click();
            validationTest("Sheet1");

            }


        public void regNull() {
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("firstname")).clear();
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("lastname")).clear();
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("html/body/app-root/app-register/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/ng2-datepicker/div/div/input")).clear();
                getDriver().findElement(By.name("radio1")).isSelected();
                Select dropdown = new Select(getDriver().findElement(By.id("countrycode")));dropdown.selectByVisibleText("India");
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("contact")).clear();
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("agree")).click();
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("submitBtn")).click();

            }   

            public void validationTest(String sheet) throws Exception{
                // Null Validations
                regNull();

                Selenium_read obj = new Selenium_read();
                ArrayList<ArrayList> tablelist=obj.readExcel(sheet);
                System.out.println(tablelist);
                for (ArrayList<String> row : tablelist){
                    regMethod(row.get(0),row.get(1),row.get(2),row.get(3),row.get(4),row.get(5));
                }

                registration_method();
                Createpassword_method();
            }


            public void regMethod(String firstName ,String lastName ,String dob, String contact,String email , String snapshot ) throws Exception {
                regNull();
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("firstname")).sendKeys(firstName);
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("lastname")).sendKeys(lastName);
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("html/body/app-root/app-register/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/ng2-datepicker/div/div/input")).sendKeys(dob);
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("one")).isEnabled();
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("contact")).sendKeys(contact);
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(email);
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("agree")).click();
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("submitBtn")).click();
                snapshot(snapshot);
                regNull();
            }
            public void registration_method()throws Exception {

                getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
                getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
                getDriver().get("https://mail.google.com/");
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("kunal@pedagogy.study");
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='identifierNext']/content/span")).click();
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("pedagogy@123");

                Thread.sleep(4000);
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();

                Thread.sleep(4000);
                List<WebElement> email = getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("div.xT>div.y6>span>b"));

                for(WebElement emailsub : email){
                    if(emailsub.getText().equals("Pedagogy : Password Reset") == true){

                           emailsub.click();
                           break;
                        }
                }

                Thread.sleep(4000);

                String mytext = getDriver().findElement(By.partialLinkText("http://52.89.55.95:3000/changepassword?email")).getText();
                 getDriver().get(mytext);
                }


            public void Createpassword_method()throws Exception {
                getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("Pedagogy@123");
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='confirmPassword']")).sendKeys("Pedagogy@123");
                getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("html/body/app-root/app-changepassword/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/button")).click();


            }


            public void setButton(String str){
                btn=str;
            }

            public void setPath(String str){
                path=str;
            }

            public void snapshot(String name) throws IOException {
                File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("D:\\PEDAGOGY SELENIUM PROJECT\\selenium\\screenshot signup\\"+path+name));
                pathlist.add("D:\\PEDAGOGY SELENIUM PROJECT\\selenium\\screenshot\\"+path+name);


        }
        }





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

   <test name="Test2">
    <classes>
     <class name="Pedagogy.login"/>
      <class name="Pedagogy.forgotPassword"/>
      <class name="Pedagogy.Registration"/>
    </classes>


   </test>



</suite> 


package common;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class generalmail2 {

    public ExtentReports report=new ExtentReports("D:\\KETAN\\ProjectReport.html");;
    public static ExtentTest logger;



    public ExtentTest getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }


    public void setLogger(ExtentTest logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }


    WebDriver driver ;
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }


    public void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }


    @BeforeSuite
    public void OpenBrowser()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://KETAN//selenium//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        logger = report.startTest("Pedagogy");
        driver.get("http://52.89.55.95:3000/");
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO , "Appliacation is up and running");


    }


    public ExtentReports getReport() {
        return report;
    }


    public void setReport(ExtentReports report) {
        this.report = report;
    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(ITestResult result) 
    {
        if (result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {
        String screenshotpath = generalScreenshot.captureScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
        String image = logger.addScreenCapture(screenshotpath);
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL , "failed", image);   
        }

        report.endTest(logger);
        report.flush();


    }


    @AfterSuite
    public void openReport(){
        driver.get("D:\\KETAN\\ProjectReport.html");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate class to declare the extent reports related classes and need to extend that class to access the object of those classes in each class where you need to generate the report for the test methods.
I have created a class(i.e. BaseTest) to declare the extent reports related classes and now I will create 2 more classes(i.e. ClassA and ClassB) to access these objects and will create a single report from these two classes.

**Here is the BaseTest class :-**

```
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.ExtentColor;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.MarkupHelper;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.ChartLocation;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;

public class BaseTest{

public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
public static ExtentReports extent;
public static ExtentTest test;

@BeforeSuite
public void setUp()
{
    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/test-output/extentReport.html");
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

    extent.setSystemInfo("OS", "Mac Sierra");
    extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "Test");
    extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
    extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "Napendra Singh");

    htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Extent report");
    htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Final Report");
}

@AfterMethod
public void getResult(ITestResult result)
{
    if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
    {
        test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test case FAILED due to below issues:", ExtentColor.RED));
        test.fail(result.getThrowable());
    }
    else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test Case PASSED", ExtentColor.GREEN));
    }
    else
    {
        test.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test Case SKIPPED", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
        test.skip(result.getThrowable());
    }
}

@AfterSuite
public void tearDown(){
    extent.flush();
   }
}
```

**Here is the class ClassA :-**

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ClassA extends BaseTest{

@Test
public void classA(){
    //Add your implementation
  }
}
```

**Here is the class ClassB :-**

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ClassB extends BaseTest{

@Test
public void classB(){
   //Add your implementation
   }
}
```

Now you can run the both classes using testng.xml file and will get the consolidated report for both the classes.

Answer (score 0):

What version of extent report are you using? Judging by your code, it is not 3rd one. But anyway, you should call report.flush() in @AfterSuite and not in the @AfterMethod.